# Make button look like text

Tags: html

I'm very new to coding in html. I'm trying to understand why this won't work on my site. I've made this button copy text when it is clicked, but I want the button to look like text. I found the attributes that should be changed, but am unsure how to apply them. My current code:

```
<button id="clip_copy" data-clipboard-text="copied text, yay">Copy Clipboard</button>

<style>
.clip_copy
 {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
</style>
<script src="zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script>
  var clip = new ZeroClipboard( 
    document.getElementById('clip_copy'), {
    moviePath: "zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you want it to look like text, why not make it text? You can associate scripts with `span` elements, too. There are several ways in which `button` elements differ from text, partly depending on browser. (Not that I would recommend making something look like text when it is functionally a button.)

Comment: From searching it seemed like it would be easier in this case, but thanks for the insight! I always like to learn more methods of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css, change `.clip_copy` to `#clip_copy`. The syntax you are using is for classes.

Comment: A better correction is to add an attribute like `class=btn` and use the class selector `.btn`, since this is more flexible: you could use the same CSS rule for different elements on a page. The rule does not make the content look like normal font: it typically has a special font and reduced font size (as per browser defaults), so to make it really look like copy text, you would need to set `font-family` to the same as copy text and `font-size: 100%`. There could still be differences, so you might want to set background and content color, too.